# Using string tuples as key for HashMap

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, hashmap, key

I need Java equivalent for following Python:

```py
In [1]: d = {}
In [2]: k = ("x","2")
In [3]: d[k] = 1
In [4]: print d[("x","y")]
```

```
1
```

Python has tuples which are hashable. I tried following in Java unsuccessfully:

```java
Map<String[], Integer> d = new HashMap<String[], Integer>();
String[] k = new String[]{"x", "y"};
d.put(k, 1);
System.out.println(d.get(k));
System.out.println(d.get(new String[]{"x", "y"}));
```

It outputs:

```
1
null
```

This means reference to `String[]` is getting hashed instead of the value.

An inefficient way I can think of is concatenating elements from `String[]` into a single `String`.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Don't use mutable objects – especially not arrays – as map keys.

Comment: Yes, just create your own `Tuple` class with `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

Comment: And no, don't pigeonhole distinct elements by using string concatenation. What would happen if you want to have keys `("aa", "b")` and `("a", "ab")`?

Comment: @Matt Excellent point.  In _most_ cases, Arrays.toString() will cover those concatenation issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arrays in Java don't provide `hashCode()` and `equals(Object)` methods, so they aren't appropriate as map keys.
What you could use instead is `Arrays.asList(string1, string1, etc)` which would give you an immutable `List`, which all the methods needed for a `Map`'s key.

Comment: While possible, I'd recommend to create an immutable list out of that. Unfortunately Java doesn't provide one, but Guava for example does. Of course you could always write one on your own, too.

Comment: @Johannes What's wrong with Collections.unmodifiableList(list)?

Comment: @haraldK: See the description of `ImmutableList` in Guava: `Unlike Collections#unmodifiableList, which is a view of a separate collection that can still change, an instance of ImmutableList contains its own private data and will never change.` So, in short terms, the difference is: if you still got an reference to the original list, you can still modify it if you used `.unmodifiableList()`

Comment: @Johannes Valid point. :-)

Comment: @Johannes H.: Since the creator of the `List` has the full control over the creation a `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(varargs))` or `Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(array.clone()))` is sufficient. There’s no reason to replace this code adding 3rd party library dependencies as *this* code is safe and the 3rd party library still wouldn’t prevent *other* code from using mutable lists.

Answer (score 12):

HashMaps use [`Object.hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) to create the hash. This, by default, uses a hash of the object that is unique for each instance - but doesn't look into any contents.

You migth want to create a tuple that overrides `hashCode()` and, in addition to that, is immutable once created:

```
public class Tuple<T> {
    private final T[] contents;

    public Tuple (T[] contents) {
        if (contents.length != 2)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.contents = contents;
    }

    public T[] getContents () {
        return this.contents.clone();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode () {
        return Arrays.deepHashCode(this.contents);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals (Object other) {
        return Arrays.deepEquals(this.contents, other.getContents());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return Arrays.deepToString(this.contents);
    }
}
```

[Edit]: Note that, if mutable objects are used instead of strings, the getter must perform a deep copy, not just a simple `clone()` to ensure immutability.

Comment: Why clone every call to hashcode()?

Comment: @user949300: I don't. I only clone the content array in the getter to make sure no changes are made to it, so the tuple is immutable.

Comment: Not sure BTW how adding up the hashcodes of both contents behaves. Maybe a more elaborate `hashCode` function is needed here. Any comments on this?

Comment: should override `equals()` also and make that `T[]` instance field as `private final` for completeness :)

Comment: @BimaleshJha: agreed, edited. Hope I didn't make any boo-boos in that quick and dirty edit ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Arrays.toString(myArray) as your key.

Comment: That's even more dirty than the approach suggested by the op (which is concatenating the strings instead of using the array)

Comment: Why "dirtier"?  First, there's little coding, and you end up with an immutable String.  And the String is bounded by [] and delimited by commas, so it is unlikely to accidentally match.  e.g. OP's scheme doesn't work for "dog","ate" vs. "do","gate".  Mine does.